# JQuery Edit Page from another Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery mobile and I have two pages both using `data-role="page"`.

Now from page 1, I have a list of items (code below) and according to what the user has selected, I want them to be displayed on Page 2. Is this possible?

**HTML**

```
<div class="FirstHomeMenuRow" style="position: absolute;left:0px;">
    <div class="firstIconleft" style="height:50%;width:16%;">
        <a href="SchoolMaterials.html">
            <img src="images/schoolmaterial.png" alt="find school materials" style="margin-left:10px;width:100%"/>
        </a>
        <div class="captionHomeIcon" style="margin-left: -2% !important;margin-top:0%;">find school materials</div>
    </div>
    <div class="firstIconleft" style="margin-right:20px !important;height:50%;width:16%;">
        <a href="UseApp.html">
            <img src="images/UseApp.png" alt="find school materials" style="width:100%;"/>
        </a>
        <div class="captionHomeIcon" style="margin-left: 1% !important;margin-top:0%;">use an app</div>
    </div>
    <div class="firstIconright" style="margin-right:20px !important;height:50%;width:16%;padding-right:6%;">
        <a href="ReadWrite.html">
            <img src="images/readwrite.png" alt="find school materials" style="width:100%;"/>
        </a>
        <div class="captionHomeIcon" style="margin-left:-3% !important;margin-top:0%;">read/write to me</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="SecondHomeMenuRow" style="position: absolute;left:0px;bottom:12%;">
    <div class="firstIconleft" style="margin-right: 15% !important;width:16%;">
        <a href="SeeWhatHappened.html"> 
            <img src="images/GoOverDay.png" alt="find school materials" style="width:100%;padding-left:20%;"/>
        </a>
        <div class="captionHomeIcon" style="margin-left:1.5%;margin-top:0%;">go over my day</div>
    </div>
    <div class="firstIconleft" style="margin-right:10px !important;width:16%;">
        <a href="SendMessage.html">
            <img src="images/sendMessage.png" alt="find school materials" style="width:100%;padding-left:20%;"/>
        </a>
        <div class="captionHomeIcon"  style="margin-left:1.5%;margin-top:0%;">send a message</div>
    </div>
    <div class="firstIconright"style="margin-right: 20% !important;width:16%;">
       <a href="HelpRead.html">
           <img src="images/helpRead.png" alt="find school materials" style="width:100%;padding-left:14%;"/>
       </a>
       <div class="captionHomeIcon" style="margin-right:59px;margin-left:1.5%;margin-top:0%;">help me read</div>
    </div>
</div>
<ul id="FavListApp">
   <li style="margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="#">Dragon App</a></li>
   <li style="margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="#">Calculator</a></li>
   <li style="margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="#">Brain Academy</a></li>
   <li style="margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="#">Root Words</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
var sel = 'url(images/FavStarSel.png)';
var unsel = 'url(images/FavStarUnSel.png)';

$('#FavListApp li > a').on("click",function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $link = $(this);
   $link.toggleClass("selected");
   $link.parent().css('listStyleImage', $link.hasClass("selected")?unsel:sel);
});
```

Comment: So you want when i click on 'Dragon App' that a new page will be loaded which has the specified content? Just simply send an GET Variable with. Or you load the content to the actual page via jQuery...

Comment: not sure why you're using jquery mobile :( if you used `@media` queries to do the css you can use POSTs and GETs (or even ajax) to do everything else. It all works on phones.

Comment: No no.. What I want is that if you choose 'Dragon App', the icon will be changed to a selected star. That's done. Then if a user goes to another page by clicking on a link I have on the page, the Dragon App text will show only

Comment: @CayceK see the edited code above. Thats why I used jquery.. css does not do what I really want

Comment: You could send the type to a PHP variable and then on the other page check the PHP variable using AJAX

Comment: I don't know how to send data over straight HTML. I'm not 100% positive that you even can. You should be using php files so that you can use POST and GET with ajax (I prefer POST for no real reason at all...). In that case you can even stay on the same page and just change the content if you wanted to. If you did not want to use ajax still use php and post to the other pages and use the passed checked item and go from there. You would change it to a form so that you can do the submit.